# How to make angular radio group label red if nothing selected?

Tags: html, css, angular, forms, angular-directive

I have an angular radio group with two radio buttons.  None of them are selected initially.  In that case, I want the label for the group to be red.  When one of them is checked, remove red.

**.html**

```
        <div>
           <label for="odr" [ngClass]="{'invalid': myForm.get('odr').invalid}">Our Dear Relative: </label>
        </div>
        <div>
           <mat-radio-group [formControl]="odr" value={{odr.value}}>
             <mat-radio-button name="odr" required>Sally</mat-radio-button>
             <mat-radio-button name="odr" required>Sue</mat-radio-button>
           </mat-radio-group>
        </div>
```

**.ts**

```
  myForm = new FormGroup({
    odr: new FormControl(''),
  });
```

**.css**

```
.invalid{
    color:"red";
}
```

So I would like the label "Our Dear Relative:" to be red when nothing is selected initially, then go back to normal if one of them is checked.  Currently, this code does not turn the label red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three of these files contain errors, especially the html file. So I'm just going to give you the right way to set it up.

```js
  myForm = new FormGroup({
    odr: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  });
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div>
    <label for="odr" [ngClass]="{ invalid: myForm.get('odr')?.invalid }">
      Our Dear Relative:
    </label>
  </div>
  <mat-radio-group id="odr" formControlName="odr">
    <mat-radio-button value="Sally">Sally</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="Sue">Sue</mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</form>
```

```css
.invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

(no quotes around `red`)

Answer (score 0):

The label is not red because your control doesn't have any validators.

This should fix your issue

```js
 myForm = new FormGroup({
    odr: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  });
```

Comment: still doesn't turn red

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should try to add Validator `required`, when you are creating the form, and additionally trigger `updateValueAndValidity`, in that case all validators will be executed and your label will be red

```
 myForm = new FormGroup({
    odr: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
 });

 myForm.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: still didn't turn red